# How to sort dataframe by some columns with nans, as if they were one column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Please consider

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [3, nan, 5, nan, 1, nan],
    'b': [nan, 2, nan, 6, nan, 4],
    'c': ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6']
})

print(df)
```

out:

```
     a    b   c
0  3.0  NaN  v1
1  NaN  2.0  v2
2  5.0  NaN  v3
3  NaN  6.0  v4
4  1.0  NaN  v5
5  NaN  4.0  v6
```

---

Guaranteed each row has a single non-nan value, I want to sort all rows by valid values on `['a', 'b']`.
Required:

```
     a    b   c
0  1.0  NaN   v5
1  NaN  2.0   v2
2  3.0  NaN   v1
3  NaN  4.0   v6
4  5.0  NaN   v3
5  NaN  6.0   v4
```

---

Please notice I am looking for a solution extendible for more than just 2 columns, and that values in each columns don't have to be followed or preceded by `nan`s, meaning there may be consecutive `nan`s or `non-nan`s in any column, as long as each row has only a single `non-nan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So maybe try `sum` with `reindex`

```
out = df.reindex(df[['a','b']].sum(1).sort_values().index).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[70]: 
     a    b   c
0  1.0  NaN  v5
1  NaN  2.0  v2
2  3.0  NaN  v1
3  NaN  4.0  v6
4  5.0  NaN  v3
5  NaN  6.0  v4
```

Comment: selected for being the most elegant and scalable.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

```
df.reindex(df.ffill(axis=1).sort_values('b').index).reset_index(drop=True)
```

### Explanation

`ffill` fills values from column `a` forwards to column `b` when they are `np.nan`.

```
>>> df.ffill(axis=1)
     a    b   c
0  3.0  3.0  v1
1  NaN  2.0  v2
2  5.0  5.0  v3
3  NaN  6.0  v4
4  1.0  1.0  v5
5  NaN  4.0  v6
```

We then `sort_values` by column `b` to get the index order.

```
>>> df.ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1).sort_values('b')
     a    b   c
4  1.0  1.0  v5
1  NaN  2.0  v2
0  3.0  3.0  v1
5  NaN  4.0  v6
2  5.0  5.0  v3
3  NaN  6.0  v4
```

Use the index above to re-order the original DataFrame and `reset_index`.

```
>>> df.reindex(df.ffill(axis=1).sort_values('b').index).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: @Gulzar - Added a step-by-step explanation which hopefully clarifies why it works.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df=(df.assign(s = df[['a','b']].sum(1))
      .sort_values('s',ignore_index=True)
      .drop('s',1))
```

**Breakdown of code:**

Since you mentioned 'Guaranteed each row has a single non-nan value

so we are adding the values of column `a` and `b` and assigning it to dataframe as column `s`:

```
df.assign(s = df[['a','b']].sum(1))

#output:

    a       b       c   s
0   3.0     NaN     v1  3.0
1   NaN     2.0     v2  2.0
2   5.0     NaN     v3  5.0
3   NaN     6.0     v4  6.0
4   1.0     NaN     v5  1.0
5   NaN     4.0     v6  4.0
```

Now we created a helper column s now we will sort values by using s:

```
df.sort_values('s',ignore_index=True)

#output:
    a       b       c   s
0   1.0     NaN     v5  1.0
1   NaN     2.0     v2  2.0
2   3.0     NaN     v1  3.0
3   NaN     4.0     v6  4.0
4   5.0     NaN     v3  5.0
5   NaN     6.0     v4  6.0
```

Finally drop the helper column:

```
df.drop('s',1)

#output
    a   b   c
0   1.0     NaN     v5
1   NaN     2.0     v2
2   3.0     NaN     v1
3   NaN     4.0     v6
4   5.0     NaN     v3
5   NaN     6.0     v4
```

Comment: Can't we use `df.assign(s = df[['a','b']].sum(1))` for the assign part ?

Comment: @Gulzar added explaination...Kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: @Psidom thank you sir for suggestion....I unnecessarly making the code more complex

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `argsort` -- combine columns `a` and `b` first, use `argsort` to find the indices that will sort the combined column and finally use the indices to sort the data frame:

```
df.loc[df.a.fillna(df.b).argsort()]

#     a    b   c
#4  1.0  NaN  v5
#1  NaN  2.0  v2
#0  3.0  NaN  v1
#5  NaN  4.0  v6
#2  5.0  NaN  v3
#3  NaN  6.0  v4
```

Comment: If multiple columns like `a` and `b`, is there a way to avoid `df.a1.fillna(df.a2).fillna(df.a3)...argsort()`?

Comment: Depending on your actual data, you can use either `ffill/bfill` or `max/min/sum` to remove `nan`s. E.g. `df[['a', 'b', 'c']].max(1).argsort()`. but they will do slightly different things when the assumption that each row contain exactly one non nan value doesn't hold.

Comment: the assumption does still hold, maybe I wasn't clear. I meant ultiple value columns, with still one valid value per row.

Comment: Then either of `max/min/sum` as example in the comment should work. You can also use `ffill` and take the last column as suggested by @not_speshal

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this :

```
df.reindex((np.where(df['a'].isna(), df['b'], df['a'])).sort()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
     a    b   c
0  1.0  NaN  v5
1  NaN  2.0  v2
2  3.0  NaN  v1
3  NaN  4.0  v6
4  5.0  NaN  v3
5  NaN  6.0  v4
```

**Explanation**:

`np.where` can be used to fill the missing values, without actually replacing them or storing it as a separate column. This would return an `ndarray` which we can be used for sorting.

Some test comparing it to other options.

```
%timeit (df.reindex((np.where(df['a'].isna(), df['b'], df['a'])).sort()).reset_index(drop=True))
252 µs ± 25.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit (df.reindex(df[['a','b']].sum(1).sort_values().index).reset_index(drop=True))
761 µs ± 23.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit (df.assign(s = df[['a','b']].sum(1)).sort_values('s',ignore_index=True).drop('s',1))
1.5 ms ± 32.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit (df.reindex(df.ffill(axis=1).sort_values('b').index).reset_index(drop=True))
2.24 ms ± 108 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This is very very nice, but doesn't scale well for more than 2 columns. Would have chosen this for just 2 though.